# Homometric sets of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Recently I was reading about various concepts relating to graphs. I came across "Homometric set". I had a quick check on Google but could only find some recent papers on the topic. Those papers dealt with some advanced results. I want to learn about this topic from basic definitions. If anyone could provide me with a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition of *homometric* in [On homometric sets in graphs](https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/55/ajc_v55_p175.pdf)

> For a vertex set $S \subseteq V(G)$ in a graph $G$, the distance multiset, $D(S)$, is the multiset of pairwise distances between vertices of $S$ in $G$. Two vertex sets are called *homometric* if their distance multisets are identical.

I wrote a snippet of Mathematica code to demonstrate it.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
(*Function to calculate the distance multiset of a vertex subset*)
DistanceMultiset[graph_, subset_] := 
  Module[{distances}, 
   distances = 
    Flatten[Table[
      GraphDistance[graph, subset[[i]], subset[[j]]], {i, 
       Length[subset]}, {j, i + 1, Length[subset]}]];
   Sort[distances]];

(*Function to check if two subsets are homometric*)
AreHomometricSubsets[graph_, subset1_, subset2_] := 
  Module[{multiset1, multiset2}, 
   multiset1 = DistanceMultiset[graph, subset1];
   multiset2 = DistanceMultiset[graph, subset2];
   multiset1 === multiset2];

(*Example usage*)
(*Create a simple undirected graph*)
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 1}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"];
GraphPlot[g]

(*Check if the subsets are homometric*)
AreHomometricSubsets[g, {1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 4}]
AreHomometricSubsets[g, {1, 4}, {5, 3}]
AreHomometricSubsets[g, {2}, {4}]
AreHomometricSubsets[g, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}]
```

[image]

```
True
True
True
False
```